# strstr() causing a segmentation fault error

Tags: c

The objective here is to take a whole text file that I dump into a buffer and then use the `strcasestr()` function to find the pointer of the word I am looking for within my buffer. It constantly gives me the segmentation fault error. At first, I thought it may be size so I tried with smaller sizes but it doesn't work either. The function only works with strings I create inside the actual code (ex : `char * bob = "bob"; char * bobsentence = "bob is cool"; strstr(bobsentence, bob);)`. Which leads me to believe it has something to do with the `fgets()`. Any help is appreciated, really stuck on this one.

```
  #define _GNU_SOURCE //to use strcasestr 

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

void textEdit(char *path, char *word){

    printf("%s\n", path);


    FILE *textFile;
    //FILE *locationFile;
    //FILE *tempFile;

    char counter[1024];
    int count = 0;

    textFile = fopen(path, "r+");
    //locationFile = fopen(path, "r+");
    //opens file to read and write and opens temp file to write

    if( textFile == NULL){ //|| tempFile == NULL || locationFile == NULL) ) {
        printf ("\nerror\n");
        return;
    }

    // SECTION : ALLOCATES MEMORY NEEDED FOR COPY TEXT IN ARRAY
    // finds number of lines to estimate total size of array needed for buffer
    while((fgets(counter, sizeof(counter), textFile)) != NULL){
        count++;
    }

    fclose(textFile);
    FILE *tempFile = fopen(path, "r+");

    count *= 1024;
    printf("%d %zu\n",count, sizeof(char));
    char *buffer = malloc(count); //1024 is the max number of characters per line in a traditional txt

    if(buffer == NULL){ //error with malloc
        return;
    }


    // SECTION : DUMPS TEXT INTO ARRAY

    if(fgets(buffer, count, tempFile) == NULL){
        printf("error");
    } //dumps all text into array

    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    char * searchedWord;

    while((searchedWord = strcasestr(buffer, word)) != NULL){


    }

    fclose(tempFile);
    //fclose(locationFile);

    free(buffer);    
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand? This is a section of my code from multiple source files that are linked. I could post the output to the console but most of it has nothing to do with this section of the code apart from the segmentation fault

Comment: Why do you expect `fgets(buffer, count, textFile);` to read the whole file?

Comment: Well the first loop counts approximately how much i need to allocate for the buffer then I use fgets and that copies all the text into it. This definitely works because I can print out the text a few lines after without a problem.

Comment: This code smells:  `count *= 1024;`  It seems to assume `fgets()` reads 1024 bytes each time.

Comment: 1) Check the return value from `fgets(buffer, count, textFile);` 2) what is word?

Comment: From `fgets` man page: read bytes ..... until n−1 bytes are read, **or a <newline> is read ...**

Comment: This code does smell... Unfortunately, I had to learn C or at least learn to make it work in a few days. I have already learned to do a recursive directory search and now I have some file IO to do so yes, it isn't great. I used 1024 because I found documentation that said traditional text editors usually fit around 1024 characters a line so it seems appropriate.

Comment: `char * bob [4] = "bob"` is just wrong. Did you mean `char *bob = "bob"` or `char *bob[4] = { "bob", NULL, NULL, NULL };`?

Comment: Let me post the whole source file, but word is a string I have to find inside the text file and then replace it with the same word but capitalised inside the same file.

Comment: So you open the file twice (one time for `tempFile` and one time for `textFile`) - correct?

Comment: Actually 3 times:
1) textFile is the one that reads and dumps into buffer
2) tempFile is the one that reads and figures out lines based on 1024 assumption
3) locationFile which I hope to use for pointer arthemetics

Comment: but how come I can print the buffer in the previous line? I am not opposed to trying the rewind but I would like to understand. Why would I need to rewind, that was the whole point of using two different file streams...

Comment: @WeatherVane - when it is two different streams (textFile, tempFile), isn't it ok?

Comment: `fclose(locationFile);` but you never open it nor initializes it - could that be your seg fault?

Comment: @A.Port - Have you tried to see if `fgets(buffer, count, textFile);` returned NULL? Did it?

Comment: Yes, tried it again and it still shows a segfault. the only time i don't get segfault is when i comment out strcasestr line. and i think that the fact it is able to print the text from the file to the console shows that the char* is not empty...

Comment: The content is exactly the same... yes it is flawed but as stated above I am a total beginner to C and while I appreciate the help given. I feel like there is more emphasis on the fact my code sucks than actually helping me out. I see you have a high score for C programming questions, I'm sure if you spent less time trying to make me reread the same page for the 4th time and had a good look this would be a walk in the park for you :)

Comment: @A.Port - when you reply to a comment use `@username` as the start of your comment. In that way we know who you are talking to. I still don't know if the `fgets` returned NULL. To me it seems that we are trying to help you but can't because you don't answer our questions

Comment: @4386427 I tried what you suggested and it does not return null. What I don't understand is how it would be null if it can print text after?

Comment: BTW: Notice that `if(fgets(buffer, count, textFile)){` is wrong. It shall be: `if(fgets(buffer, count, textFile) == NULL){`

Comment: @4386427 I have implemented your suggestion but does not work unfortunately :/

Comment: @4386427 Yeah I already edited that in my own code but you couldn't know that sorry.

Comment: But now you updated to `!= NULL` That is still wrong. It is an error when it returns NULL. So us `== NULL`

Comment: This is the worst so sorry...

Comment: @4386427 so after correcting another grievous mistake, I can confirm that fgets returns null. but i comes back to something i asked earlier. Why is it able to print right after if fgets returns null?

Comment: @A.Port It should **not** be able to do that. There is something you are misunderstanding but currently I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: @A.Port Take a look a the code here https://ideone.com/760oag   Insert the if-blocks into your code and run it. What result do you get?

Comment: word is null. I'm just going to figure it out from here. Or restart because this is patch work at this point...

Answer (score 2):

It looks that you forgot to initialize count variable to 0:

```
int count = 0;
```

You increment it and it can contain any random value, even negative.

Also, note that your utilization of **strstr** doesn't look correct. The function returns the pointer to *first* occurrence that matches. Note, that it doesn't remember already found matches, so if match exists it should loop forever in this loop. Instead it should look like:

```
char *pos = buffer;
while((pos = strcasestr(pos, word)) != NULL){
  searchedWord = pos;
  /* do something with searchedWord but remember that it belongs to  
   allocated buffer and can't be used after free() */
  pos++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that but still doesn't fix my problem

Comment: @A.Port Do you have segfault if you remove the loop with strcasestr ?

Comment: I do not! Another detail is that the text content does not print once i replace the strcasestr line but without it does.